# Dúvidas iniciais sobre o framework Electron

Tags: aplicação-desktop, electron

Boa noite, estou querendo começar a usar o Electron para desenvolver aplicações Desktop, mas eu tenho algumas dúvidas iniciais. As minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

Como faço a persistência da minha aplicação no Electron utilizando um banco de dados, por exemplo o Mysql?

Quando a minha aplicação estiver totalmente pronta como eu faço para criar uma versão para distribuir para uso?

Toda a lógica da minha aplicação a parte de inserir dados no banco, recuperar esses dados, verificar login e etc vai ser feita com JavaScript ou eu posso utilizar outra linguagem como o Java?

A aplicação que foi desenvolvida no framework pode ser estendida de alguma forma para a Web ou só pode ser usada como desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Para cada banco de dados você devera instalar uma biblioteca a do mysql por exemplo pode ser instalada por npm `npm install mysql` tão simples quanto isso, vou deixar um link com um exemplo simples da implementação [Link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/259/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-electron-framework)

Este link [Como gerar arquivo para distribuição](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution) vai mostrar como gerar os arquivos para distribuição.

Pelo que percebi na sua pergunta o aplicativo realmente vai precisar ser escrito em JavaScript. A menos que a ideia seja criar um servidor/API para os dados e deixar apenas a lógica para o aplicativo.

Para replicar o aplicativo electron para a web são necessárias muitas adaptações. creio que chega a ser inviável.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai um pouco da minha experiência e espero que te ajude:

Electron é basicamente a View de uma aplicação desktop, portanto no código do backend, pode ser Node.js (neste caso usaria JavaScript) ou uma API/Rest que também pode ser escrita em Node.js ou mesmo em Java, Web Api .Net Core.

Se você for adotar qualquer das tecnologias acima, o que você vai ter é essa estrutura:

- View em Electron (telas em HTML, CSS e JavaScript)
- Requisições HTTP GET, POST, PATH, UPDATE, DELETE para uma API/Rest ou SOAP (um WebService)

A vantagem aqui de você usar uma Web API é que se você em algum momento quiser usar essa mesma API para trocar a View para usar em um app Mobile ou em um Web Site você vai fazer as mesmas requisições.

No caso essa API pode ser instalada em ambiente Windows e, neste caso, você vai ter que verificar dentro das suas ferramentas de desenvolvimento o que melhor lhe atende (Noje.js, Api JAVA, Web APi C#...).

Com relação à distribuição de uma aplicação Electron, você pode empacotar a mesma usando o 
electron-packager: https://github.com/electron/electron-packager .Ele vai te possibilitar compilar para Windows, MacOS e Linux e gerar o pacote de sua aplicação.

Obs: View são as telas em que o usuário interage com a aplicação.